# Output java variable value to be parsed in JS

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I have this code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var endpoint = "http://localhost:8080/LWP/in.jsp?code=" + "<% out.println(request.getParameter("code")); %>";

    window.opener.location.href = endpoint;

    window.close();
    </script>
```

What I expect it to do is redirect the page which opened the browser window this is processing in to

```
http://localhost:8080/LWP/in.jsp?code=<code here>
```

If I remove the <% out.println() %> portion of the script, it works fine, and I am redirected as expected (minus the value being passed in).

What am I doing incorrectly with the output of the parameter?

I also tried removing out.println. Still does not work.

Comment: Can you show what the actual rendered js code looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Had to assign the value to a new variable, then use that.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<% String code = request.getParameter("code"); %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var code = "<%=code%>";
    var endpoint = "http://localhost:8080/LWP/in.jsp?code=" + code;

window.opener.location.href = endpoint;

window.close();
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: actually the reason this succeeded is because you did not use out.println hence no new line was sent.  If you only use out.print (without the ln) you would be ok since it would not output a new line...  If you look at the html output when you use out.println you will see that the var endpoint line does not end with ";, it actually has a new line, and then comes the "; and this is what messes up your script.